# iOS Safari how to catch event when iFrame content is being cleared by browser back button?

Tags: javascript, iframe

My webpage has an iframe, when pressing Safari back button, I found that the iframe's content being cleaned, and it displays a blank page.

I used to use events such as "popstate" to catch the back button click, then I will close iframe after its content has been cleared. however it seems to be no longer able to get these events in latest Safari in iOS 14.2

After the back button click, the iframe's content was update to this:

```
<iframe id="myiframe">
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

But I didn't catch any events, such as popstate, onunload, onbeforeunload, etc.

What event should I be listening to under this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I used the iframe.onload event for detecting back button press, and detect if the the iframe's location href has been updated to blank page:

```
        testframe.onload = function () {
            if (testframe.contentWindow.location.href === "about:blank") {
                closeIframe();
            }
        };
```